# No result set when Where clause with ID not used

Tags: mysql, toad-data-point

I am trying to figure out why my code does not return any data when I take out the Account_ID. I want it to run and find every Account_ID that meets the join conditions and the fields I want returned. This is in MySQL and I have looked around here and Googled but have not found anything like this or just not put it correctly. So, below is code and if anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it. The code should return 1 row per Account_ID
I am not used to using MySQL. Version 5.6.34 using Toad Data-Point to run sql script.
Thanks Dan

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    pd.ACCOUNT_ID                 
    , do.MEMBER_NAME
    , do.GENDER
    , MaxDate.EarlyDATE AS ACTIVITY_DATE
    , MaxDate.LateDATE  AS LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE
    , pd.NUMBER_WKS        
    ... more fields after this
    Joins below
    FROM ZZ_Program_Details pd 
        LEFT JOIN ZZ_Demographics do 
         ON do.ACCOUNT_ID = pd.ACCOUNT_ID
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT cl.ACCOUNT_ID
        , min(cl.activity_date)  AS EarlyDATE
        , cl1.activity_date AS LateDATE
        , cl1.scheduling_selection
        , cl.ATND_STATUS_THIS_INTERVAL         
        , cl.WEIGHT_STATUS_FOR_INTERVAL        
        , TRUNCATE(cl.WEIGHT_WHEN_ENROLLED,2)   AS WEIGHT_WHEN_ENROLLED
        , TRUNCATE(cl.WEIGHT_AT_INTERVAL_END,2) AS WEIGHT_AT_INTERVAL_END
        FROM ZZ_Class_Attendance cl
         INNER JOIN ZZ_Class_Attendance cl1
          ON cl1.account_id = cl.ACCOUNT_ID 
        WHERE cl1.ACTIVITY_DATE > cl.ACTIVITY_DATE
         /*and cl.account_id = '47F74C65BA8BB02DE053BC010B0AF714'*/
        ) AS MaxDate 
    INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT ESRA.healthfleet_member_id
      , ESRA.Sponsor
      , ESRA.uhc_region
      , ESRA.uhc_major_market
      , ESRA.uhc_minor_market AS ESRA_UHC_MINOR_MARKET
      , ESRA.policy_number AS ESRA_POLICY_NBR
      , ESRA.relationship_code
      , sf.Market_Segment
      , sf.UHC_Minor_Market   AS SF_UHC_MINOR_MARKET
      , sf.CLIENT_NAME
      , sf.Client_Owner
      , sf.Payer_Effective_Date
    FROM reporting_adhoc.ZZ_ESRA_People ESRA
     LEFT JOIN reporting_adhoc.ZZ_Salesforce sf
      ON sf.Policy_Number = ESRA.policy_number
    /*WHERE ESRA.healthfleet_member_id='47F74C65BA8BB02DE053BC010B0AF714'*/
    GROUP BY ESRA.healthfleet_member_id
    , ESRA.Sponsor, ESRA.uhc_region
    , ESRA.uhc_major_market
    , ESRA.uhc_minor_market
    , ESRA.relationship_code
    , sf.Market_Segment
    , sf.UHC_Minor_Market
    , sf.CLIENT_NAME
    , sf.Client_Owner, ESRA.policy_number
    , sf.Payer_Effective_Date
    ) ESRA_DATA 

    ON MaxDate.ACCOUNT_ID = pd.ACCOUNT_ID
    AND ESRA_DATA.healthfleet_member_id = pd.ACCOUNT_ID

    /*WHERE pd.account_id = '47F74C65BA8BB02DE053BC010B0AF714'* --with this 
    it works fine */ 
    WHERE pd.account_id > 0 --an attempt with getting all account_ids

    GROUP BY
    pd.ACCOUNT_ID                 
    , do.MEMBER_NAME  
    , do.GENDER
    , MaxDate.EarlyDATE
    , MaxDate.LateDATE
    ... rest of fields
    ORDER BY pd.ACCOUNT_ID
```

Comment: I don't have a concrete solution, but the first thing that springs to mind is that perhaps `ESRA.healthfleet_member_id` uses a case sensitive collation and some or all of the letters in the field are lower case.

Comment: If `account_id` is a string, why are you comparing it to a number `0`?

Comment: Also, nothing in the query indicates you would get a single row per account id.

Comment: Also2: Without the WHERE (or an appropriate GROUP BY), the MaxDate query is only going to return a single row....with effectively random values for all fields except EarlyDate.

Comment: Some Simple SQL Rules to Live By: `DISTINCT is *usually* bad` http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2006/03/14/9289.aspx *Your use of distinct in this query is distinctly bad.**

Comment: @Uueerdo/Barmar - The Account_id or healthfleet_member_id are varchar. So when I compare them it works fine. Where I have the Where clause in each subquery is to speed up the query so I only look for that 1 ID instead of millions. I get back 1 row of data which is what I want. The data is correct. The problem is when I take out the WHERE clause looking for that 1 ID that I get nothing back. I will take out the Distinct as mentioned by -used_By_already. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Without access to your tables and data we probably cannot propose a definite answer, and as your query has missing pieces it makes it even more of a guessing game.

Let's start here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ---------- bad bad
      pd.ACCOUNT_ID
    , MaxDate.EarlyDATE AS ACTIVITY_DATE
    , MaxDate.LateDATE  AS LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE

FROM ZZ_Program_Details pd
LEFT JOIN ZZ_Demographics do ON do.ACCOUNT_ID = pd.ACCOUNT_ID
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT  ---------- bad bad
            cl.ACCOUNT_ID
          , MIN(cl.activity_date) AS EarlyDATE
          , cl1.activity_date     AS LateDATE
      FROM ZZ_Class_Attendance cl
      INNER JOIN ZZ_Class_Attendance cl1 ON cl1.account_id = cl.ACCOUNT_ID
      WHERE cl1.ACTIVITY_DATE > cl.ACTIVITY_DATE

      -- no GROUP BY, so how do your get MIN() or MAX() ?

   ) AS MaxDate ON 
                    ( WHAT???? )
```

Start by breaking your big query into smaller chunks, like you see above. **Does this partial query work?** It may not because you have tried to use DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY and the join conditions are unknown as well.

Also note that you have used an INNER JOIN. If that subquery `MaxDate` fails to return any matching rows then the overall query will won't return rows either. Reconsider each INNER JOIN (perhaps try them as LEFT JOINS).

Once you get that partial query working, add the next join and add the relevant columns to the top select clause. Work on this part of the query until it succeeds, move to the next and repeat until you have a working query.

Do please try to avoid use of "select distinct" in complex queries involving multiple joins. This is not good practice.

---

You might find these queries will help you decide which tables (or subqueries) need left joins or not:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct pd.ACCOUNT_ID) acct_c, COUNT(*) row_c
FROM ZZ_Program_Details pd 
;

SELECT COUNT(distinct pd.ACCOUNT_ID) acct_c, COUNT(*) row_c
FROM ZZ_Program_Details pd 
INNER JOIN ZZ_Demographics do ON pd.ACCOUNT_ID = do.ACCOUNT_ID
;

SELECT COUNT(distinct pd.ACCOUNT_ID) acct_c, COUNT(*) row_c
FROM ZZ_Program_Details pd 
LEFT JOIN ZZ_Demographics do ON pd.ACCOUNT_ID = do.ACCOUNT_ID
;

SELECT COUNT(distinct pd.ACCOUNT_ID) acct_c, COUNT(*) row_c
FROM ZZ_Program_Details pd 
INNER JOIN ZZ_Class_Attendance cl ON pd.ACCOUNT_ID = cl.ACCOUNT_ID
INNER JOIN ZZ_Class_Attendance cl1 ON cl1.account_id = cl.ACCOUNT_ID 
;

SELECT COUNT(distinct pd.ACCOUNT_ID) acct_c, COUNT(*) row_c
FROM ZZ_Program_Details pd 
LEFT JOIN ZZ_Class_Attendance cl ON pd.ACCOUNT_ID = cl.ACCOUNT_ID
LEFT JOIN ZZ_Class_Attendance cl1 ON cl1.account_id = cl.ACCOUNT_ID 
;

SELECT COUNT(distinct pd.ACCOUNT_ID) acct_c, COUNT(*) row_c
FROM ZZ_Program_Details pd 
INNER JOIN reporting_adhoc.ZZ_ESRA_People ESRA ON pd.ACCOUNT_ID = ESRA.healthfleet_member_id
INNER JOIN reporting_adhoc.ZZ_Salesforce sf ON sf.Policy_Number = ESRA.policy_number
;

SELECT COUNT(distinct pd.ACCOUNT_ID) acct_c, COUNT(*) row_c
FROM ZZ_Program_Details pd 
LEFT JOIN reporting_adhoc.ZZ_ESRA_People ESRA ON pd.ACCOUNT_ID = ESRA.healthfleet_member_id
LEFT JOIN reporting_adhoc.ZZ_Salesforce sf ON sf.Policy_Number = ESRA.policy_number
;
```

Comment: I will get rid of the rid of the DISTINCT and the subqueries do run fine by themselves. I have tested and they returned the data as expected. Will update you tomorrow. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It isn't just that the subqueries run by themselves, but does the whole query still work when each of them is joined together. Also: it isn't just a mater of removing the word "distinct". In some cases you should be using GROUP BY instead. Eventually you want the final result to have unique rows, but often his means you have to work hard to achieve that. Simply tossing "select distinct" on top of a big query isn't a good approach.

Comment: I changed the joins and removed anything that was below them and added it all into the Select statement. The Class_Attendance table is an INNER Join and Demographics is a LEFT Join all on the Account_ID. I do get data back now without using a Account_ID. However, I only get back 768 and should be getting everything back from Program_Details which has 203k Account_IDs. When I do a simple count of Account_IDs that is the number. So, I have made headway. Thanks.

Comment: I added some small queries that may help you decide how to perform the joins. If the count of distinct account id's remains the same as the first result then that join will not hide any accounts. Otherwise that join has stopped access to some rows.

Comment: I took everyone's advice by checking data out and then simplify the joins by creating tables to handle all the sub-selects that were being performed and causing such big delays. This has resulted in getting results in a fast time instead of taking forever or if anything would come back. Also, found out some of the data types were not the same. That helps to have the same! :)

Comment: Definitely sounds way better, well done. And yes, it will certainly be better if the data types are the same. Will you accept this as the answer?